# Powershell version 2 Configuration System Failed to Initialize

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am creating a script using PowerShell to make a http request to an endpoint. I know starting from PowerShell version 3, I can use `Invoke-RestMethod` or `Invoke-WebRequest`, but the script is required to be compatible with PowerShell version 2.
As I have googled and read many forums, the most common solution is to use the .Net class `System.Net.WebRequest`. I am executing the below lines:

```
$Uri = "https://url"
$Web = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($Uri)
```

And I am facing below error:

```
Create : Exception calling "Create" with "1" argument(s): "Configuration system failed to initialize"
At line:1 char:32
+ [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create <<<< ($Uri)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Can you please help what might caused this problem?

Comment: The webrequest class does not have an [overloaded constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.-ctor) with one parameter.. You need to obtain the object without parameter and then set the RequestUri property: `$Web = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create(); $Web.RequestUri = $Uri`

Comment: Thanks for your comment Theo.
I just tried your option and it throws the below error.  It looks like it does have an overload. When using my commands in powershell version 3 or greater, it does work. Only in powershell 2 I am facing this issue.
I want to emphasize that I am opening powershell version 2 using commad : "powershell -version 2".

Create : Cannot find an overload for "Create" and the argument count: "0".
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Comment: Hmmmm. Same here when i try that in a 'powershell -version 2' console on my Windows 10 box. Can you try on a machine that actually does have only PowerShell 2.0 installed? If there it does work, then running 'powershell -version 2' apparently does not fully emulate that version (or the underlying .Net)..

Comment: In this case, with this command I have used in PSv2, the reason of the error was because of an unrecognize configuration section in (C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe.Config line 2). 
I just deleted this file and it worked.

I found the solution here:
https://github.com/chocolatey-community/chocolatey-coreteampackages/issues/1342#issuecomment-538668949

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. Good find!